# Why does this expression evaluate to false?

Tags: python

I thought `range()` returns a list of numbers . why does the `all()` function return a false for this

```
all(range(100))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `range(100)` contains 0, and the boolean value of 0 is `False`:

```
In [1]: bool(0)
Out[1]: False
```

while for any other number it evaluates to `True`. The function `all` only returns `True` when all of the elements of its argument evaluate to `True`, see its [manual](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) (the `if` statement in the given example implicitly takes the boolean value of every item). See here the difference of including 0 or not:

```
In [2]: all(range(10)) # 0..9
Out[2]: False

In [3]: all(range(1,10)) # 1..9
Out[3]: True
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the first number generated by `range` is 0.

```
>>>range(10)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

# 0 is evaluated to false in boolean expressions
>>>bool(0)
True

# making range start at 1
>>>all(range(1, 100))
True
```

Comment: Watch out for your test of "falsiness", because `[] == False` is `False` even though `not []` is `True`.  It's more accurate to test falsiness with `not` or by explicitly converting to `bool`.  The `0 == False` test worked only because of the way `False` implemented.

Comment: @SethMMorton Thanks for the heads up. I'll update the answer to `bool(0)`. But I would expect that if `[] == False` then `not []` be equal true, don't you?

Comment: No.  `not` or `bool` uses the `__nonzero__` method of an object (`__bool__` in python 3.x).  `==` uses `__eq__`.  When you use `==` it expects another list, so when comparing itself to `False` it sees it is not the same and returns `False`.  When you use `not` or `bool`, it "looks inside itself" to determine if it is `False` or `True`.